# Should you avoid top-level imports in a file defining Airflow operators

Tags: airflow

From the Airflow documentation:

> You should avoid writing the top level code which is not necessary to create Operators and build DAG relations between them. [...] One of the important factors impacting DAG loading time, that might be overlooked by Python developers is that top-level imports might take surprisingly a lot of time and they can generate a lot of overhead and this can be easily avoided by converting them to local imports inside Python callables for example.

([source](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code))

So DAG files should avoid big top-level imports.

My question is: does this also impact other files from which a DAG file may import, and notably files defining operators?

Example:

```
class MyOp(ParentClass):
    def execute(self, context):
        import numpy as np
        np.blabla
```

^ is this

```
import numpy as np

class MyOp(ParentClass):
    def execute(self, context):
        np.blabla
```

^ betther than this?

Comment: I have the same question a year later. Got any insights?

Comment: @m01010011 all I can say is I remember testing it and concluding that the impact  on DAG parse time was negligible

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
class MyOp(ParentClass):
    def execute(self, context):
        import numpy as np
        np.blabla ^ is this

import numpy as np

class MyOp(ParentClass):
    def execute(self, context):
        np.blabla ^ betther than this?
```

In general, **yes**. Importing stuff that is not strictly required for the creation of the DAG hinders the performance of the DAG parser.

Since `numpy` is only required to run the `execute` function of the operator, you don't need to import it at top-level.

This, of course, as you mentioned sometimes is negligible. But I've had a case in which we defined a Snowflake connection at top-level code and every time the DAG was parsed, we saw a log of the connection getting created. We removed it right-away after realizing it got created every minute (or every time the scheduler picked the DAG up).